# How to add @ symbol before column value and separate with ' , '?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add @ symbol to a column name and separated each by ','

I tried with `substring()` as the following:

```
declare @tmp varchar(250) SET @tmp = '' 
select @tmp = @tmp + COLUMN_NAME + ', @'  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME ='tbl_emp'
select SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp)) as new column
```

The column names are:

```
+--------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  |
+--------------+
| empName      |
| workinhDate  |
| Workinghour  |
+--------------+
```

The output should be like:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|             ColumnNames             |
+-------------------------------------+
|  @empName,@workinhDate,@Workinghour |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant:

```
DECLARE @tmp VARCHAR(250)
SET @tmp = ''
SELECT  @tmp = @tmp + '@' + COLUMN_NAME + ', '
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_emp'

SELECT  LEFT(@tmp, LEN(@tmp) - 1)
```

Also, `substring` in sql server is 1 based, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the following statement may help:

```
DECLARE @tmp varchar(max) = '' 

SELECT @tmp = @tmp + ', @' + COLUMN_NAME  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_emp'

SELECT STUFF(@tmp, 1, 2, '') as [new column]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Substring:

```
declare @tmp varchar(250) SET @tmp = '@'
select @tmp = @tmp + COLUMN_NAME + ',@' FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME ='tbl_emp'
select SUBSTRING(@tmp,0,LEN(@tmp)-1) as ColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `STUFF()` function with `FOR XML PATH` as

```
SELECT STUFF(
       (  SELECT ', @' + COLUMN_NAME
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_emp'
          FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 1, 2, ''
       ) Result;
```

If you really need to store the results in a variable then

```
DECLARE @tmp VARCHAR(250);

SELECT  @tmp = STUFF(
                      (  SELECT ', @' + COLUMN_NAME
                         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                         WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_emp'
                         FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, ''
                    );
SELECT @tmp;
```